# In linear mixed model, should I include both sampling year and sites as random effects?

Tags: r, mixed-model, biostatistics

I would like to study the influences of environmental variables (e.g.water temperature, nutrient) on chlorophylla using a multiyear dataset comprising of observations from 10 sites.

I am confused about the selection of random effects, I am wondering which way should I use

```
chla ~ WT + TN + TP + (1|site)
```

or

```
chla ~ WT + TN + TP + (1|site) + (1|Year)
```

the fit results of them are quite different

Comment: @benimwolfspelz Thank you for your kindly reply. It is quite useful for me, my data does have only 1 measurements for each site-year combination. I became confused that the model fit improved largely when both the site and Year are included as random effects. I will try crossValidated with similar problems next time, Tks again!

Comment: Please edit your question to show how the fits differ. It certainly seems that you need to incorporate both `site` and `year` in some way into your model, but with only 1 observation per combination of `site` and `year` there might be some problems with having an over-specified model. The more information you can provide about your data and analysis the better answer you can get. Please provide that information by editing the question, as comments are easy to overlook and can get deleted.